# How do I load this HTML file for my own visualization?

Tags: javascript, html, deep-learning

For this problem, I have not many options as I am not sure which direction I should be heading.

Now I am studying Deep Learning frequently and I want to toy around with [Stanford's CS231N's Convolutional Neural Network Demo](https://github.com/cs231n/cs231n.github.io/blob/master/assets/conv-demo/index.html) as I find it extremely user friendly. The visuals are embedded in this [website](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/). I really want to toy around with this but I do not know how and where to start.

I have knowledge of Python and VS-Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the index.html file from the above link.

If you look closely in index.html, there are two scripts you need that to make it work.

[image: scripts_from_index.html]

Copy the files from the demo folder from the link and the files structure should look like this(same as in the github demo)

[image]

[image]

Now double click on index.html and choose a browser to open this work and should work as expected. And you can also modify the code and reload the index.html to see live changes.